# Redues UITextfield border width between two UITextfields

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have used UItextfield border style as BorderStyle. On keeping two uitextfield closer, dark line occurs so how to reduces UITextfield border width between two old and new password textfields?

[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkZbT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because both the UITextfields have 0px gap between them. Leave a 1 px gap between the two textfields, they'll be fine

[Edit]

Use custom borders using CALayer 
Creating a bottom border will look something like this :

```
var bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, textField.frame.size.height - 1, textField.frame.size.width, 1.0);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

Repeat this for all other sides of the textfield. Don't draw layer for the bottom part of the username and top part of password

Comment: Giridhar. As per app design requirement. I dont want 1 px gap between two UITextfields. I want thin border between UITextfields.

Comment: In that case, add custom borders, using CALayer, the code for the bottom border alone will look something like this

var bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, textField.frame.size.height - 1, textField.frame.size.width, 1.0);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

Comment: I tried this but not working. Please see below code   CALayer *bottomBorder, *topBorder;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, oldPwdTxtFld.frame.size.height - 1, oldPwdTxtFld.frame.size.width, 1.0);
    topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, NwPwdTxtFld.frame.size.height, NwPwdTxtFld.frame.size.width, 1.0);
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [oldPwdTxtFld.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
    [NwPwdTxtFld.layer addSublayer:topBorder];

Comment: Did you set the textfield border property to no?

Comment: Yes. I have set UITextField border style to None.